# MEGA 2560: Crashes when Adafruit FT6206 ctp function called using code with Interrupt

Tags: arduino, interrupt, encoder, adafruit

Arduino MEGA 2560: I want an interrupt to execute when a button push occurs on a rotary encoder. I have the code working. However, if I add a function call to Adafruit's FT6206 library the MEGA 2560 hangs. (Evidence of this is that the Serial.println command text is cut-off mid stream of display.) Why?

Hardware setup: rotary encoder push button has two pins: one side is connected to the interrupt pin with a pull-up for power, and the other side tied to ground.

No other hardware or shield is connected. The hardware set up is only the rotary encoder wired to the MEGA 2560 to demonstrate the issue in its simplest form; however, I have the same issue when the TFT display shield is installed.

The MEGA 2560 is the INLAND brand. The rotary encoder is from Adafruit.

Here is the code:

```
#include "Adafruit_FT6206.h"

// Global Variables

const byte  RotarybuttonPin  = 21; 
volatile byte Rotarybutton_Pressed_Flag; 
TS_Point       touchpoint;

Adafruit_FT6206  ctp = Adafruit_FT6206(); 


void setup() {
  ctp.begin(70);            
  Serial.begin(115200);    
  pinMode(RotarybuttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);                                         
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RotarybuttonPin), Button_Pin_ISR, LOW); 
}


void Button_Pin_ISR() {Rotarybutton_Pressed_Flag = 1;} 


void loop() { 

  Serial.println("In Loop!");
  touchpoint = WAIT_FOR_SCREEN_TOUCH();    
}


TS_Point WAIT_FOR_SCREEN_TOUCH() {

  CHECK_ROTARY_ENCODER();
  Serial.println("Entering 'While'");

  //This next line locks the MEGA 2560 up with ctp function call
  while (!ctp.touched()) {CHECK_ROTARY_ENCODER();}             
  return (touchpoint);
}


void CHECK_ROTARY_ENCODER() {

if (Rotarybutton_Pressed_Flag) {
   Serial.println("PRESSED"); 
    Rotarybutton_Pressed_Flag = 0;                                 
}
else {Serial.println("NOT PRESSED");} 
delay(190);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue and wanted to share the solution with the community.

The MEGA2560 has six interrupt pins: 2, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21.  However, when using the FT6205 which is part of Adafruit's 2.8" TFT shield, the interrupt pins 20 and 21 become unavailable as they are being used by the I2C bus.  Interrupts are limited to pins 2, 3, 18, and 19.

This limitation is a bit problematic as the TFT shield blocks easy access to pins 2 and 3.  However, it is possible to share a header pin with the shield with a #22 gauge wire.

Pins 18 and 19 are not blocked by the TFT shield and could be used. However, I want to use these pins for their interrupts in detecting clockwise and counterclockwise rotary encoder movement.